# Are there any ferry tickets /passes in Japan that cover multiple ferries between multiple islands?

Tags: japan, tickets, ferries, islands, okinawa

I know you can buy JR Rail passes for travel by train all over Japan.

But Japan also has many islands and I assume quite a few of them are serviced by ferries.

What I'm wondering is whether there is anything resembling a "ferry network" where you can buy a single ticket or pass that covers a range of ferries between different islands.

If not for the entire country, then at least for particular areas with many islands, such as Okinawa. Or even for any group of three, four, or five islands.

(If there are several such passes each serving small groups of islands this may be changed to a Community Wiki question.)

Comment: Ferries are very infrequent to many islands (unlike trains) and it would likely not be cheaper to do even if it were offered as a result. You could always call one of the major ferry companies and try to arrange such a thing, but chances are you'll be better off buying individual tickets for whatever legs you want to take.

Comment: No. Since the ferries are operated by individual companies, and since very few people travel across a larger network, there is no such thing.

Comment: @uncovery: If you are sure of this submit it as an answer and I will vote for it and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on [this map](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2355.html), Japanese ferries are operated by different companies (every color is a different one). This is by the way similar to the Japanese railway and subway system. The difference from the Subway system however is that people rarely travel over several ferry routes. To make a cross-company ferry ticket is quite difficult, and due to the little usage, this was never done.

So, in short, there is no such general pass for ferries.